# Devise and Active Admin using a single model error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, activeadmin

My application requires a single model for both Devise and Active Admin for the User and I want to distinguish the super admin, admin and user based on the role which is present in the Profile model and I followed [this link by dan doezema](http://dan.doezema.com/2012/02/how-to-implement-a-single-user-model-with-rails-activeadmin-and-devise/). Please help me as I am new to the rails world and do not know what to do in this problem.
I have deleted the admin user which was created by default. My user.rb file in the app/admin folder is:

```
    ActiveAdmin.register User do
        form do |f|
            f.inputs "User Details" do
                f.input :email
            end
            f.buttons
        end
    end
```

Here I have used User because I want to use the User generated by the devise. My users.rb file in app/admin is:

```
    ActiveAdmin.register User do
        permit_params :email
        index do
            selectable_column
            id_column
            column :email
            column :current_sign_in_at
            column :sign_in_count
            column :created_at
            actions
        end
        filter :email
        filter :current_sign_in_at
        filter :sign_in_count
        filter :created_at
        form do |f|
            f.inputs do
                f.input :email
                end
                f.actions
            end
        end
```

I did not change the dashboard.rb file in app/admin. The application_controller.rb file is:

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
        protect_from_forgery with: :exception
        def authenticate_admin_user!
            authenticate_user!
            unless current_user.profile.role == 'super_admin'
                flash[:alert] = "Unauthorized Access!"
                redirect_to root_path
            end
        end
    end
```

I have removed the following route from the routes.rb file

```
    devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
```

I have also destroyed the AdminUser model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure Active Admin settings in `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`. See [Active Admin Authentication](https://activeadmin.info/1-general-configuration.html#authentication)

Specifically, you'll want to set: `config.authentication_method` and `config.current_user_method` to match the methods you are defining in your `ApplicationController`.

Example:

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  protected

  def authenticate_admin_user!
    authenticate_user!
    unless current_user.profile.role == 'super_admin'
      flash[:alert] = "Unauthorized Access!"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  def current_admin_user
    return unless current_user&.profile.role == 'super_admin'
    current_user
  end
end
```

config/initializers/active_admin.rb

```
config.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!
config.current_user_method = :current_admin_user
```

Alternatively, you could just authenticate current user and authorise admin views by role. See [Active Admin Authorization Adapter](https://activeadmin.info/13-authorization-adapter.html)